# Is a redirect absolutely necessary upon a successful transaction?

Tags: php, redirect, transactions, include

I am writing a transaction page whereby upon a successful transaction, the user is redirected to a "transact_success.php" page. I am wondering if there is any concern, security or otherwise if instead of:

```
if(transaction is successful)
{
 header("Location: transact_success.php");
 exit();
}
```

I use:

```
if(transaction is successful)
{
 include("/var/www/include/transact_success.inc");
 exit();
}
```

to display the same information on the transaction page itself.

I ask this question because the first case is usually what I observe on many websites, some with mulitple redirects. I presume this is to prevent people from hitting the "back" button, causing repeated transactions.

If prior to processing a transaction, I am going to check the database for the state of transaction, is such redirect still necessary? Can I just proceed to use the second method instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you can avoid duplicating the action (via refresh for instance) you're good with the second approach, redirects are useful because they reduce code duplication and act in a "web-like way".

Take a look at the [Post/Redirect/Get Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).